# Configuring typings with gulp-typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped, gulp-typescript

I have a JavaScript app composed of multiple .js files and one .ts file. I use the latest version of TypeScript with its allowJs flag. I want to compile my app using a gulp task but I keep getting these errors:

```
x:/XXX/typings/main/ambient/angular/index.d.ts(65,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
x:/XXX/typings/main/ambient/angular/index.d.ts(65,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.
```

Here is my typings.json:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20160318102130",
    "d3": "registry:dt/d3#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160316155526"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs":true,
        "noLib": false,
        "target":"ES5"
  }
}
```

Extract of my gulpfile

```
var tsProject = plugins.typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json');
var pathsSrc = {
        ts: [ "typings/main.d.ts", 'client/app/**/*.js', 'client/app/**/*.ts', '!**/nameOfMyOnlyTsFile.js']}

function ts() {
        return gulp.src(pathsSrc.ts)
            .pipe(plugins.typescript(tsProject))
            .pipe(plugins.concat('xxxxxx.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(pathsDest.js));
    }
 function tsWithNotification() {
        return ts()
            .pipe(plugins.notify({
                title:"Gulp TS",
                message: "TS copied successfully.",
                onLast: true
            }));
    }

gulp.task('ts', tsWithNotification);
```

Answer (score 0):

At last I targeted ES6, but I got some new errors.

```
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Iterable'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'IterableIterator'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Iterator'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Symbol'.
error TS2468: Cannot find global value 'Symbol'.
```

Giving up for the moment, I will use classes later...